# How to undo - Java denied permission to run in IE9

Tags: windows-7, security, java, internet-explorer-9

I installed Java 1.7u25 on a user's laptop.  The first time he ran IE9 he received a security warning about Java, stating that this type of program could be harmful. He did not grant permission to run it and also checked the box not to ask about that program again.  I need to re-enable JAVA in IE9.  I have looked at the IE settings, the Java console, uninstalled and reinstalled Java, upgrade Java to 1.7u40 and searched the registry.  I am totally stumped as to how to undo what my helpful end user did.  Any wisdom shed on this issue would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "Scripting of Java applets" option enabled?

If you go into Internet Options > Security > Select the zone > Custom Level.

Then scroll down to the scripting section, it should be in there.

[image]